# How to put dynamic image tag into modal?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am new to Bootstrap, wondering how do i put dynamic image tag into modal for display as a lightbox. 
I tried with image tag referring to variable in Ajax, but it doesnt work.

Thanks for your time

Javascript code:

```
   <script>
        function getpic( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return null;
  else
    return results[1];
}
        var frank_param1 = gup( 'Listingid' );
        $("#display12").append(frank_param1);


            $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "specpic.php",
   data: {"data":frank_param1},
                dataType:'json',
            success: function(data2){ 
                  for(var i=0; i<data2.length; i++) { 

                      var image2= data2[i].pic;
                      var image = "http://test.info/Bootstraptest/test/"+data2[i].pic;
                       var html1 = "<div data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal>"+ "<img src='"+image+"'  height=200 width=200>" +"</div>";

          $("#display13").append(html1);  
            }}
         });





    </script>
```

Modal Html code

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">



      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="#" onclick="src=image2">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you give image name with it it's path.If yes then check that image exist at given location.

Comment: yer i did, but in the console.log it is returning an error saying the path is http://test.info/Bootstraptest/test/image instead of the image name.

Comment: where the image i am not able to found any image in URL?

Comment: Cos it is dynamic image, you have to log into the system then it pulls the id and using the id to pull the images.

Comment: And that is the problem that i am having the part image shouldnt be image, it should be the name of the image. It is not getting the name